# Python - aggregate data at 30 second intervals to 12 hour intervals

Tags: python

I have some data in a python data series  like this, there are rows for every 30 secs 24 hours a day

```
2022-03-31 23:57:30+10:00    163.440459

2022-03-31 23:58:00+10:00    163.521460

2022-03-31 23:58:30+10:00    163.608255

2022-03-31 23:59:00+10:00    163.698986

2022-03-31 23:59:30+10:00    163.790968
```

I need to aggregate the data to 12 hour intervals specifically
6:00am and 6:00pm  for each day ie

```
2022-03-31 06:00:00+10:00   sum of values for group by 
2022-03-31 18:00:00+10:00   sum of values for group by
```

No idea how to start and ideas welcomed thank you

Comment: You can write a function to map the time into one of the 2 groups, e.g. "23:57:30+10:00" -> "18:00:00+10:00" and "08:02:11+ 10:00" -> "06:00:00+10:00 ", then do the aggregation based on this grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made something to cover your description of how you need it to work.

```
num = open('r.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()  #this is the list that was provided on a txt
list6 = []     #vars for later
list18 = []
days = []
for line in num:    #looks throug the lines
    if line != '':    #makes sure its not a blank
        day = line[5:7]      #gets the day from line
        days.append(day)    # saves the day
        transform = line[11:13]    #gets the hour from line
        value = line.split("    ")[1]    #gets the aggregrated value
        compare = int(transform)    #transforms to work with easyer
        if compare >= 18 or compare < 6:    #checks if its after or equal to hour 18 or less than 6
            list18.append(float(value))
        else:    #else its writes it down
            list6.append(float(value))
print(f'2022-{days[0]}-31 06:00:00+10:00    {list6}')    #result part1
print(f'2022-{days[0]}-31 18:00:00+10:00    {list18}')    #result part2
```

It works with messing with the string arrangement.